# Matching a type T to a list of case statements

Tags: c++, recursion, template-meta-programming, c++17

I have a compile-time `switch_` template that matches a given type `T` to a list of `case_` statements (of which `default_` is a special case, no pun intended). A `case<Key, Value` is two-parameter class for which its `Key` is matched against the class `T` using a `match<T, Key>` variable template, which is a modified `std::is_same_v`.

```
#include <cstdint>      // uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t
#include <type_traits>  // conditional_t, is_same_v, true_type, false_type

namespace meta {

template<auto N>
using int_c = std::integral_constant<decltype(N), N>;

struct true_;
struct false_;

template<class Key, class Value>
struct case_;

template<class Value>
using default_ = case_<true_, Value>;

template<class T, class Key>
constexpr auto match = std::is_same_v<T, Key>;

template<class T> constexpr auto match<T, true_> = true;
template<class T> constexpr auto match<true_, T> = true;

template<class T> constexpr auto match<T, false_> = false;
template<class T> constexpr auto match<false_, T> = false;

template<class T, class... Cases>
struct switch_;

template<class T, class... Cases>
using switch_t = typename switch_<T, Cases...>::type;

template<class T, class Key, class Value>
struct switch_<T, case_<Key, Value>>
:
        std::conditional<match<T, Key>, Value, false_>
{};

template<class T, class Key, class Value, class _, class Else>
struct switch_<T, case_<Key, Value>, case_<_, Else>>
:
        std::conditional<match<T, Key>, Value, Else>
{};

template<class T, class Key, class Value, class Head, class... Tails>
struct switch_<T, case_<Key, Value>, Head, Tails...>
:
        std::conditional<match<T, Key>, Value, switch_t<T, Head, Tails...>>
        //                                     ^^^^^^^^ <= can this recursion be avoided?
{};

}   // namespace meta

using namespace meta;

template<auto N>
using unsigned_ = switch_t<         // will return associated type of first match, case_ has "break" semantics
    int_c<N>,
    case_<int_c<8>, uint8_t>,
    case_<int_c<16>, uint16_t>,
    case_<int_c<32>, uint32_t>,
    case_<int_c<64>, uint64_t>,
    default_<unsigned>              // will always match, so put this last!
>;

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<unsigned_<  8>, uint8_t>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<unsigned_< 16>, uint16_t>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<unsigned_< 32>, uint32_t>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<unsigned_< 64>, uint64_t>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<unsigned_<128>, unsigned>);
}
```

[**Live Example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7Vyoi45iVY8q91UA) using gcc 7.1 in C++17 mode.

**Question**: Please comment on the clarity of the code. In particular, I am curious if the compile-time recursion over the variadic parameter pack can somehow be avoided by mapping it to `tuple` or `integer_sequence` land where there are efficient compiler-intrinsics that pay off for long lists.

**UPDATE**: See [this link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZXBU3TIhQJGMk0pb) for the updated code with changes that reflects the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think returning the artificial `false_` in case of no match is a good idea. Just return nothing, and you won't need `false_` at all. Replace

> ```
> : std::conditional<match<T, Key>, Value, false_>
> ```

with

```
: std::enable_if<match<T, Key>, Value>
```

It's interesting that while you support an explicit default-case, the last case is always treated as the default case anyway, if it isn't the only case. Oops?

> ```
> template<class T, class Key, class Value, class _, class Else>
> struct switch_<T, case_<Key, Value>, case_<_, Else>>
> :
>         std::conditional<match<T, Key>, Value, Else>
> {};
> ```

By the way, if you restrict the default-case to being the last case, which you should consider doing anyway, you can replace `match` with `std::is_same` and some changes to `switch_`, making `default_` its own class-template. Might be worth it.

What I failed to find is any way to avoid the recursion, sorry. I hope you can make good use of my feedback anyway.

Modified code:

```
namespace meta {

// Only for the example-program:
template<auto N>
using int_c = std::integral_constant<decltype(N), N>;

template<class Key, class Value>
struct case_;

template<class Value>
struct default_;

template<class T, class... Cases>
struct switch_
{
    static_assert(!sizeof...(Cases), "this meta::switch_ is malformed");
}

template<class T, class Value>
struct switch_<T, default_<Value>>
: std::enable_if<true, Value>
{}

template<class T, class Key, class Value, class... Tail>
struct switch_<T, case_<Key, Value>, Tail...>
: std::conditional_t<std::is_same<T, Key>(),
    std::enable_if<true, Value>,
    switch_<T, Tail...>>
{}

template<class T, class... Cases>
using switch_t = typename switch_<T, Cases...>::type;

}   // namespace meta
```

Comment: Thanks, that was useful feedback! I had completely overlooked the possibility of using `enable_if` for single-valued outcomes. I have updated [**the example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZXBU3TIhQJGMk0pb). I've eliminated `match`, made `default_` a separate incomplete type, and do a `static_assert` that there are no remaining cases after it. Also, I made an empty `switch_` valid by returning a special marker type `nonematch`. All in all only 3 partial specializations, so the recursion doesn't seem to bad after all.